# how to prove this recurrence of determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, recurrence-relations, determinant, recreational-mathematics

the question is :
Let Dn = $[a_{ij}]$n × n be a (n × n) determinant with the following conditions:
$$a_{ij} = 4 ;i=j$$
$$a_{ij} = 2 ;|i-j|=1$$
$$a_{ij} = 0 ; otherwise$$
then we have to prove that :
$$ D_n = 4D_{n-1} - 4D_{n-2}$$
my approach:

I found $D_1 =4 ,D_2=12, D_3=32$
but I don't know how to prove this as higher order determinants are take much more time to get calculated and I couldn't find a pattern  .Thanks for all help.

Comment: In fact $D_n=(n+1)2^n$, which is perhaps easier to prove if we halve the matrix, so its leading diagonal is all $2$s and the next-to-leading diagonals are all $1$s, and we wish to show the resulting determinant is $n+1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
D_n
&=\overbrace{\begin{vmatrix}
4&2&0&\cdots&0&0&0\\
2&4&2&\cdots&0&0&0\\
0&2&4&\cdots&0&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots&4&2&0\\
0&0&0&\cdots&2&4&2\\
0&0&0&\cdots&0&2&4\\
\end{vmatrix}}^{n\text{ columns}}\\
&=
4\cdot\overbrace{\begin{vmatrix}
4&2&0&\cdots&0&0&0\\
2&4&2&\cdots&0&0&0\\
0&2&4&\cdots&0&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots&4&2&0\\
0&0&0&\cdots&2&4&2\\
0&0&0&\cdots&0&2&4\\
\end{vmatrix}}^{(n-1)\text{ columns}}
-2\cdot\overbrace{\begin{vmatrix}
2&2&0&\cdots&0&0&0\\
0&4&2&\cdots&0&0&0\\
0&2&4&\cdots&0&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots&4&2&0\\
0&0&0&\cdots&2&4&2\\
0&0&0&\cdots&0&2&4\\
\end{vmatrix}}^{(n-1)\text{ columns}}\quad\text{(expanding first row)}\\
&=
4\cdot\overbrace{\begin{vmatrix}
4&2&0&\cdots&0&0&0\\
2&4&2&\cdots&0&0&0\\
0&2&4&\cdots&0&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots&4&2&0\\
0&0&0&\cdots&2&4&2\\
0&0&0&\cdots&0&2&4\\
\end{vmatrix}}^{(n-1)\text{ columns}}
-4\cdot\overbrace{\begin{vmatrix}
4&2&0&\cdots&0&0&0\\
2&4&2&\cdots&0&0&0\\
0&2&4&\cdots&0&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots&4&2&0\\
0&0&0&\cdots&2&4&2\\
0&0&0&\cdots&0&2&4\\
\end{vmatrix}}^{(n-2)\text{ columns}}\quad\text{(expanding first column)}\\
&=4D_{n-1}-4D_{n-2}\\
\end{align}

Comment: understood it,thanks for your support